# Best approach to get stock market data from MySQL and show to all users?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, websocket, redis

I'm building a web application for automated signals on stocks and crypto.
There is a huge amount of data stored in a MySQL database.
Currently, I'm trying to **get data from MySQL and broadcast it using websockets to the clients via Laravel Events & Redis.**
**The question is**, is this a good approach to fire the event on route, then get the data from database in the event class, then broadcast it to users via a channel on websocket?
I think it may **consume more resources of server & also bandwidth** as everytime a user opens that page, the **event fires** and tries to get the data from database.
**What is the best way** to get data from database **one time in a row**, and then broadcast it to all users who are visiting the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should categories the data with current data and historical data.
When data gets very large, it's important to think about exactly what kind of queries you're going to be running on it, and then optimize the data structure (backend, file format, column layout, etc) to suit your queries.
If the intraday data is relatively low-frequency (e.g., 1-minute bars or lower), that can probably be put into the SQL DB as well. If it's very large (e.g., tick-by-tick data from multiple exchanges), then SQL might not be a great choice. In that case, you will want to go with something like HDF5 files, or even a custom file format depending on what kind of queries you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, but the approach here is to use laravel + redis and socket.io
I wanted something that works well in this way.